# Is it possible to have two versions of Vagrant in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, vagrant

in my company we are using Vagrant 1.3 and I cannot update it because the Vagrant files we are using in our development environment are tied to that version, and they won't work anymore.

I am thinking about installing the new version of Vagrant in a different folder, but I don't know how to do it and if it would work. I need to use Laravel Homestead, which is only compatible with vagrant 1.6 onwards...

Any ideas? Thank you

(I am using Max OS X 10.10.1 Yosemite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have a similar problem. I need 1.4.3 and can't update to 1.7.4. After a lot of experiments I think I found a solution. It involves some ugly hacking but it did the trick for me. I wrote a gist describing how I did it:

https://gist.github.com/arielpontes/b2d783fde85e1b3237b8

Let me know if it works for the versions you want :)

**[ UPDATE ]** Here's a copy/paste from the instructions in the gist:

### 1. Install [VirtualBox 4.3](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3) and [Vagrant 1.4.3](http://www.vagrantup.com/download-archive/v1.4.3.html)

Vagrant 1.4.3 doesn't work with newer versions of VirtualBox (>4.3). During this experiment I messed up all my installations several times, so I'm installing everything from scratch (just go to the download page, download the dmg and run the pkg installer normally).

### 2. Hack the Vagrant 1.4.3 installation

```
$ sudo mv /Applications/Vagrant /Applications/Vagrant\ 1.4.3
$ sudo ln -Fs /Applications/Vagrant\ 1.4.3/bin/vagrant /usr/bin/vagrant
```

* *This is for legacy Vagrant versions, which are installed in `/Applications/Vagrant`.*

### 3. Install Vagrant 1.7.4

Vagrant 1.7.4 is organized differently from 1.4.3 and, when running a command that requires application data for the first time (e.g. `vagrant box list`), it will update its file structure, breaking the 1.4.3 installation. To prevent this from happening, run:

```
$ sudo mv ~/.vagrant.d ~/.vagrant143.d
```

* *You can run this after installing 1.7.4, just make sure you don't run any vagrant command before.*

Now you're safe to install Vagrant 1.7.4. When you're done you can check if everything is ok:

```
$ rehash
$ vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.7.4
```

* *If you're still getting 1.4.3, just open a new shell.*

### 4. Hack the Vagrant 1.7.4 installation

```
$ sudo mv /opt/vagrant /opt/vagrant174
$ sudo ln -Fs /opt/vagrant174/bin/vagrant /usr/bin/vagrant
```

* *This is for new Vagrant versions, which are installed in `/opt/vagrant`.*

### 5. Create shell commands to switch Vagrant

Add these lines to your ~/.bash_profile (or ~/.zshrc or whatever you use):

```
alias vagrant143='sudo ln -Fs /Applications/Vagrant\ 1.4.3/bin/vagrant /usr/bin/vagrant && mv ~/.vagrant.d ~/.vagrant174.d && mv ~/.vagrant143.d ~/.vagrant.d'
alias vagrant174='sudo ln -Fs /opt/vagrant174/bin/vagrant /usr/bin/vagrant && mv ~/.vagrant.d ~/.vagrant143.d && mv ~/.vagrant174.d ~/.vagrant.d'
```

### That's it!

Now you can easily switch between versions by running `vagrant143` or `vagrant174`:

```
$ vagrant143
$ vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.4.3
$ vagrant174
$ vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.7.4
```

Note that your vagrant boxes will be stored separately, so if you add a box while using a version of Vagrant it won't be visible from the other version:

```
$ vagrant143
$ vagrant box add trusty64
$ vagrant box list
trusty64 (virtualbox)
$ vagrant174
$ vagrant box list
There are no installed boxes! Use `vagrant box add` to add some.
```

These are all a bunch of ugly hacks and I can't promise a new Vagrant version won't break it, but for the moment it does the trick for me.

Comment: Hi Ariel, glad you found a solution. Could you perhaps post the solution (or a summary of it) here? That way all the necessary info about the problem and its solution is contained in the same page. Thanks!

Comment: thanks Ariel! my company finally ugraded to 1.7 but I like your solution